# Hadoop: start-all.sh fails to start Hadoop services

Tags: hadoop

Hadoop service was working smoothly. But all of a sudden "start-all.sh" started failing with following error message.

> WARNING: Attempting to start all Apache Hadoop daemons as vishnudas in
>   10 seconds. WARNING: This is not a recommended production deployment
>   configuration. WARNING: Use CTRL-C to abort. Starting namenodes on
>   [localhost] ERROR: namenode can only be executed by master. Starting
>   datanodes ERROR: datanode can only be executed by master. Starting
>   secondary namenodes [vishnudas-VirtualBox] ERROR: secondarynamenode
>   can only be executed by master. Starting resourcemanager ERROR:
>   resourcemanager can only be executed by master. Starting nodemanagers
>   ERROR: nodemanager can only be executed by master.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried executing using sudo privilege?